# Liverwire filamentphp

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-filament

Please I need your help. My filaments works fine with 127.0.0.1:8000 (Via artisan serve)
But, once I uploaded it to my cPanel, I got an error 404 get livewire/livewire.js. I was able to manipulate this but got another error 404 Post livewire/update

It works fine on 127.0.0.1:8000 using php artisan serve
But doesn't work on usual local host i.e http://localhost/myfolder

Comment: You probably have a webserver configuration rule that is specific for .js files and the livewire.js file is dynamically generated. You need to either remove that rule or omit that URL specifically.

Answer (score 1):

try rebuilding the livewire config and publish the assets using livewire on the live server

ie
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire:config
then
php artisan livewire:publish --assets

Answer (score 0):

By default, Livewire will serve its JavaScript assets from the following URL:

```
http://localhost/livewire/livewire.js
```

To use a custom JavaScript asset endpoint, you can register your own route(`myfolder/routes/web.php`) inside like this.

```
Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
  return Route::get('/myfolder/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
});
```

Now, Livewire will load its JavaScript like so:

```
<script src="/myfolder/livewire/livewire.js" ...
```

If you use Filament, you also need to customize Livewire's update endpoint.
Livewire will know to use this endpoint for all component updates.

```
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
  return Route::post('/myfolder/livewire/update', $handle);
});
```

Then, instead of using `/livewire/update`, Livewire will send component updates to `/myfolder/livewire/update`.

I hope this answer will help you.